# Error No such file or directory: _pulsar.so

Tags: apache-pulsar, python-pulsar

when installing `pulsar-client` for python by running the below steps

```
$ git clone https://github.com/apache/pulsar
$ cd pulsar/pulsar-client-cpp/python
$ sudo python setup.py install
```

encountered the error

> No such file or directory: _pulsar.so

Comment: The similar issue is reported in github: https://github.com/apache/pulsar/issues/4540

Comment: It's fixed by running the comment

**"$ sudo execstack -c /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_pulsar.so"**